# 複数カラムでGroupした結果をHashでなくActiveRecord::relationで取得したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

### やりたいこと

Userが例えば `生まれた年(=year)`と`出身の都道府県(:prefecture_id)`カラムを持っているとします。

そこから 「同じ生まれ年」かつ「同じ出身都道府県」のユーザーが3人以上いる場合、そのユーザーの一覧を取得したいです。

出力結果がHashであるため期待する結果ではないのですが、集計して多い順に並び替える処理は以下で出来ました。

```
User.group(:year, :prefecture_id).having("count_all > 3").order("count_all DESC").count
```

この出力結果は `{[1990, 13]=>4, [1996,2]=>3}` のように、生まれ年と都道府県ID、一致した数になっています。

ここから、この「生まれ年」と「都道府県ID」を持つユーザーを一覧を取得するにはどのような手段がありますでしょうか？

---

上でのHashにUserIdがあれば、pluckとwhereを用いて取得することも出来るかと思いましたが、Idがあると適切なGroupにならないためそれも出来なかったです。。

### 試したこと

パフォーマンスは悪いですが、以下などが一応期待した動作でした。
しかしデータ数が10万件とかなるとパフォーマンスが非常に悪いため避けたいと思っています。

```
user_hash = User.all.group_by{ |user| [ user[:year], user[:prefecture_id] ] }
@users = user_hash.values.select{ |user| 3 < user.size }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User.joins(<<~SQL)
  INNER JOIN (
    #{User.select("year, prefecture_id, count(*) as count_all").group(:year, :prefecture_id).having("count_all > ?", 3).to_sql}
  ) as year_pref
  ON users.year = year_pref.year
  AND users.prefecture_id = year_pref.prefecture_id
SQL
```

のようにすると、望みの User についての relation が得られるのではないか、と思っていますが、いかがでしょうか?

## 追記@2020/07/21

「該当件数」でソートしたい場合には、 sort 条件を relation に含めれば良いと思っています。 e.g.

```
User.joins(<<~SQL).order("year_pref.count_all DESC")
  INNER JOIN (
    #{User.select("year, prefecture_id, count(*) as count_all").group(:year, :prefecture_id).having("count_all > ?", 3).to_sql}
  ) as year_pref
  ON users.year = year_pref.year
  AND users.prefecture_id = year_pref.prefecture_id
SQL
```

Comment: `User.group(:year, :prefecture_id).having("count_all > 3").to_sql`
を
`User.select("year, prefecture_id, count(*) as count_all").group(:year, :prefecture_id).having("count_all > ?", 3).to_sql`
にするとrelationで値を得ることは出来ました！ありがとうございます。
ただ表示順はバラバラになっており、可能なら表示順を数の多い順に並べる方法がないかも併せて解決出来ればと思っています。

Comment: @hatsu 回答に追記しました。